# how to solve the error (expected identifier before'(' token) in C

Tags: c

its my first question here..
In the following code. It keeps giving me the following error in the scanf lines: Expected identifier before '(' token.
i dont know how to solve it..

```
typedef struct avion
{
    int code;
    int capacite;
    char etat[1];
    int date;
    int nvols;
} avion;
typedef struct element *list;
typedef struct element
{
    avion A;
    struct element *svt;
} element;
        
list *Modifier(list* av)   
    {
        list *p=av;
        int c;
        printf("\n------------La Modification--------------\n");
        printf("\nDonner le code de l'avion que vous voulez modifier... :");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        while(av!=NULL) 
        {
            if ((av->(A.code)) == c)
            {   
            printf("\nL'avion existe dans la liste...");
            printf("\nDonner le nouveau code:");
            scanf("%d",&av->(A.code));
            printf("\nDonner la nouvelle capacite...:");
            scanf("%d",av->(A.capacite));
            printf("\nDonner le nouveau etat...:");
            scanf("%s",av->(A.etat));
            printf("\nDonner la nouvelle date de fabrication...:");
            scanf("%d",av->(A.date));
            printf("\nDonner le nouveau nombre de vols assures...:");
            scanf("%d",(av->(A.nvols)));
            return p;
            }
            (*p)=p ->(svt);
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is `A`? Other notes: `while(av!=NULL) ` but `av` does not change inside the loop. And `scanf("%d",av->(A.date));` you need to pass an address here (maybe you are).

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: `&av->(A.code)` this is probably not correct. I would think it shoud be `&av->A.code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "`expected identifier before '(' token`" error occurs because you are using `->` operator to access a field of a `struct` and, instead of passing the field identifier, you are passing a `'('` character.

Here is the list of errors.

1. `av->(A.code)` is bad syntax. If `av` is a pointer to a `struct`
   that contains a `struct` field called `A` and you want to access the
   field `code` of `A`, use `av->A.code`;
2. `(*p) = p->(svt)` is also bad syntax. If you want `p` to point to
   the next element of the list, witch I assumed is pointed by the
   field `svt`, use `p = p->svt`;
3. You forgot to pass the address of your integers when you use
   `scanf()` with `"%d"` identifier, inserting the `'&'` character
   before the variable names;
4. Replace `typedef struct element *list` for `typedef struct element list`;
5. Note that the function will return after the first element on whose
   `code` field equals `c`. If you meant to do that, you need to return
   a `list *` after the while loop. I suggest you to return `NULL` to
   signalize no element of the list was modified.

Here is my suggestion.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct avion {
    int code;
    int capacite;
    char etat[1];
    int date;
    int nvols;
} avion;

typedef struct element {
    avion A;
    struct element *svt;
} element;

typedef struct element list;

list *modifier(list* av) {
    list *p=av;
    int c;
    printf("\n------------La Modification--------------\n");
    printf("\nDonner le code de l'avion que vous voulez modifier...: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    while (av!=NULL) {
        if (av->A.code == c) {   
            printf("\nL'avion existe dans la liste...");
            printf("\nDonner le nouveau code: ");
            scanf("%d", &av->A.code);
            printf("\nDonner la nouvelle capacite...: ");
            scanf("%d", &av->A.capacite);
            printf("\nDonner le nouveau etat...: ");
            scanf("%s", av->A.etat);
            printf("\nDonner la nouvelle date de fabrication...: ");
            scanf("%d", &av->A.date);
            printf("\nDonner le nouveau nombre de vols assures...: ");
            scanf("%d", &av->A.nvols);
            return p;
        }
        p = p->svt;
    }
    return NULL;
 }
```

Comment: ,I took into consideration your suggestion.the error of the expected identifier has disappeared. but a new error has appeared :/  (request for member 'A' in something not a structure or union)..

Comment: @samiaaa15 did you replaced `typedef struct element *list` for `typedef struct element list`? If you define an `element` as a pointer to a `list`, you cannot access a field of a `av` using `->` operator, because `av` is a pointer to `list`, witch is an `element`, witch is a `struct`, witch **IS NOT** a pointer to a `struct`. The `->` operator only works for pointers to a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly (or not), the same error appears if you have say
`#define VALUE`
and then, later

```
if (VALUE) {
    // do something
}
```

The solution is to define it with an actual value, like
`#define VALUE (1)`

Comment: I fail to see how this is relevant to the question or how it provides an answer.